# Gaussian shape link function for glm binomial regression?

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, link-function, radial-basis

Link functions are typically sigmoid. The idea being that the underlying data is fitted to the curve with an increase in the predictor summation gives an increase in the response. However, could one use a link function that is Gaussian shaped? Such that there is a "sweet spot" with a trailing off on each side?

Doing more reading, I am asking if a glm can be used with a radial basis function similar to a radial basis function (RBF) network. You may ask why I wish for this? I need the model to be very interpretable. White box only, no black boxes allowed.

[image]

I could address this situation by using logit logistic regression with polynomial expansion of the predictors or by introducing addition variables with a knot pivot.

I am just wondering if there was a more direct path.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, polynomial expansions *are* the direct path.